# How to print the address value of a pointer in a C program?

Tags: c, pointers, output

I'm trying to learn how to use the pointer in a C program;  my example is as follows:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int * tab = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
        int a = 10;
        int *p;
        p  = &a;
        printf("the address of a is %d \n",&a);    
        printf("the address of a using the pointer is %p \n",p);    
        printf("the address of tab is %d \n",tab);    
    }
```

I'm trying to print the address of `a`, the address value inside of `p` and where the first byte of the `tab` begins.

I can get hexadecimal values when using `"%p"`, but I'm willing the decimal value of the addresses.

**Edit :** On this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1DcpcgSUXw&index=2&list=PL2_aWCzGMAwLZp6LMUKI3cc7pgGsasm2_)  [image](https://image.prntscr.com/image/Ycq33ax2SAqvfxrOM_CnHQ.png), someone has used `"%d"` to print a decimal value for a pointer address, and it has confused me.

Comment: First of all - what is the point of decimal value of an address?

Comment: `"%d"` works with `int`.  It may not work with `&a`.  Suggest `printf("%p\n",(void*) &a);`

Comment: To print address of pointers, you should use `%p`. Forget the decimal interpretation of pointers, the hexadecimal representation is far superior.

Comment: later i will try to manipulte the tab variable , and i will test if every cell in the tab is 4 byte , so may be i wiill do tab+8 bytes to get the value of a specific   cell ,here it's a simple example , with decimal it will be easy for me .

Comment: @chux your solution give me a hexadecimal value.

Comment: @zakzak The output format of `%p` is implementation defined, but it is _defined_.  You code gave decimal output, but not necessarily correct output.  Your goal seems to wants any simple decimal output and not necessarily correct decimal output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To print a *decimal* version of an object pointer, 1st convert the pointer to an integer.  Best to use the optional type `uintptr_t`.

> The following type (`uintptr_t`) designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type (`uintptr_t`) ... C11dr §7.20.1.4 1

```
#include <inttypes.h>
uintptr_t d = (uintptr_t)(void *) &a;
```

Then print it.
Some info on [PRIuPTR](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/inttypes.h.html)

```
printf("%" PRIuPTR "\n", d);
```

---

For pre-C99 code, consider a direct cast to `unsigned long`.  [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48309191/2410359)

---

OP later commented

"... i will try to manipulate the tab variable , and i will test if every cell in the tab is 4 byte , so may be i will do tab+8 bytes to get the value of a specific cell , here it's a simple example , with decimal it will be easy for me ."

This is a questionable approach as the decimalization of a pointer may not provide the continuous numeric model expected.  This post this may be good for learning, but with OP providing more details in another post, even better ideas could be given for the higher level problem.

Answer (score 5):

First, be aware that addresses are often "number-like" but might not be (e.g. remember the segment+offset notion of far addresses on 1980-era 16 bits x86 PCs).

Then, the integral type the most similar to pointers is `intptr_t` (signed) or `uintptr_t` (unsigned) - both from [`<stdint.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).

You might cast that to a `long long` (hoping that they are not smaller than pointers), e.g.

```
 printf("address of a in decimal is %lld\n", (long long) (intptr_t) (&a));
```

But really, why do you want to show an address in such a fashion? I see no need for it (e.g. debuggers or linkers are generally showing addresses in hexa, which is probably what `%p`  does).

Notice that the C11 standard (see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), §7.21.6.2, p315) does not say much about `%p` for printing pointer:

> The  argument  shall  be  a  pointer  to `void`.  The  value  of  the  pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner.

I'm understanding the above in a way where printing `Hello ⭔` for any pointer would be an acceptable and standard conforming behavior. In practice, implementations print pointers in a way similar to what linkers and debuggers do, and don't behave in a silly way (but I understand they could).

At last, the actual concrete "numerical" value of a pointer is not really important and can vary greatly from one execution to the next (e.g. because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR)).

Answer (score 4):

For printing an "address" (actually a pointer) `"%p"` is the most common method (note the necessary cast to `void*`). If you need the address in decimal instead of hexadecimal, you can convert the pointer into an integral value; this is well defined in C (cf. [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6) online C standard draft):

> 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> (6) Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
>   previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the
>   result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
>   undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any
>   integer type.

So the code could look as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a =10;
    int *p = &a;
    p  = &a;

    unsigned long long addrAsInt = (unsigned long long)p;

    printf("the adress of a is %llu \n",addrAsInt);
    printf("the adress of a using the pointer is %p \n",(void*)p);
}
```

Comment: I would use `unsigned long long` above instead of `uint64_t`, even if they are usually the same.

Comment: Why not #include <stdint.h> and use size_t? Seems preferable to either uint64_t or unsigned long long. size_t may well be the same as either of those but uint64_t is very likely to be the same as unsigned long long while size_t is merely likely to be the same.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir `size_t` may be as small a `uint16_t`.  Converting to a wide type like `unsigned long long` or `uintmax_t`, which are both at least 64-bit,  reduces the chance of information loss.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see the pointer as a decimal integer, cast it to `unsigned long` and print it with `%lu` format. While this isn't guaranteed by the standard, it should work in most implementations.

```
printf("the address of a is %lu\n", (unsigned long)&a);
```

Comment: your solution worked for me , i would prefere this because it's simple. i have to thank every One .

Comment: @zakzak It is simple - and with pointers wider than `long`, may provide confusing results.

Comment: chux's answer is the right one, don't prefer *simple* answers to right answers...